# How to stop player on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<object width="300" height="300">
<param name="src" value="" id="param">
<param name="autoplay" value="false">
<param name="controller" value="true">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
<embed src="" autostart="false" loop="false" width="300" height="300"
controller="true" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="filcontainer"></embed>
</object>
<a href="#"class="close"/>**Close it**</a>
```

this is a audio player in popup window , how can i stop playing player when user click on close anchor , currently audio is continues playing when close link is clicked and popup is closed??

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        var myPlayer = document.getElementById('filcontainer');
        myPlayer.stopVideo();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PbWpv/)**

***Edit:***

**[Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PbWpv/18/)**

Comment: +1, the only one that mentions `.ready()`

Comment: player.stopVideo(); what i have to write at the place of "player" in this syntax?

Comment: i am testing using that code if it worked i will definitely accept it..:)

Comment: @VishalSuthar its not working vishal..:(

Comment: Warning: Empty string passed to getElementById().
 this warning is generated when i run the code

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of video HTML 5 functions and events : http://www.chipwreck.de/blog/2010/03/01/html-5-video-dom-attributes-and-events/

You could pause your video like this :

```
var myvid = document.getElementById('vid');

$('a').click(function(e) { 
    myvid.pause();
    return false
});
```